# Post Build Event Exited with Code 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to clean up the release folder using Post Build event so i delete `.xml` and `.pdb` files and try to copy all dll files into custom lib folder bug i get `Post Build Exited with Code 1`

My code:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release del "$(TargetDir)*.xml", "$(TargetDir)*.pdb"
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release xcopy "$(TargetDir)\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)\lib\"
```

The 2 commands are separated by new line as shown...
Also Lib folder exists.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), a return code of `1` means "**No files were found to copy.**".

Comment: In addition, since you write the file names in line on in quotes, I also suggest to do the same in line two. E.g. `xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)lib\"`.

Comment: @UweKeim neither work idk why

Comment: @UweKeim also the dll files are in the same folder as the exe i just want to move them then to a custom folder...

Comment: A good way to debug post build events is to copy the commands from the output window (with the macros expanded) and try it in your console.

Comment: @UweKeim visual studio seems not to separate the commands...

Answer (score 8):

Instead of

```
xcopy $(TargetDir)*.dll $(TargetDir)lib\
```

you should use

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)lib\"
```

to handle spaces in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Try open VS with Run as Administrator -> open project -> build.

Answer (score 2):

First, try using `$(TargetDir)\`, as there are some variables which return without a trailing slash, which would concatenate your path so you're looking for `bin\Debuglib\` instead of `bin\Debug\lib`

As pointed out by @Uwe Keim, [Return Code 1 means no files found to copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx). This can also happen if you're pointed at an invalid folder, furthering the idea that you may need that `\`.

There is also the possibility that the `del` command has failed, though the same technet article on del does not indicate any return codes. Some forum sources indicate a return code of 1 may indicate a failed deletion.

Comment: The del works alone, but when i add the xcopy command on a new line visual studio seems not separating them

Comment: Error 1 The command "if Release == Release del "\bin\Release\*.xml", "\bin\Release\*.pdb"
if Release == Release xcopy \bin\Release\\*.dll \bin\Release\\lib\
" exited with code 4.

Comment: Adding the slash like you describe helped eliminate the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This modification worked for me:

```
del *.XML, *.pdb
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)lib\"
```

1). Omit target directory variable in del command

2). /y option in xcopy
Note from Microsoft Help page: /y : Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)lib\"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative path in Copy command then make sure the parent directory refers to appropriate directory you intend for otherwise you will get exit code 1 error.

For ex:

```
copy "C:\SolnFolder\project1\release\bin\xyz.dll" "..\MainProject\bin\x86\"
```

Here, Project1 and MainProject coexist at SolnFolder. When I thought of copying xyz.dll into MainProject's x86 folder, it failed because ..\ used in copy command refers release folder of source path instead of SolnFolder. Hence, the below solved the issue:

```
copy "C:\SolnFolder\project1\release\bin\xyz.dll" "..\..\..\MainProject\bin\x86\"
```

NOTE: Also, **make sure quotes are used with every relative path**

Answer (score 0):

I always end my pre/post build events with the line `@set ERRORLEVEL=0`, since programs like xcopy seem to return a non-zero error even with success.